# Localizing global variables

Tags: global-variables, abap

When using the Extended Program Check, I get the following warning:

> Do not declare fields and field symbols (`variable name`) globally.

This is from declaring global data before the selection screen. The obvious solution is that they should be declared locally in a subroutine.

If I decide to do this, the data will now be out of scope for the other subroutines, so I would end up creating something to the effect of a `main()` function from C or Java. This sounds like a good idea - however, events such as `INITIALIZATION` are not allowed to be inside of subroutines, meaning that it forces a break in scope.

Observe the sample program below:

```
REPORT Z_EXAMPLE.
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK upload WITH FRAME TITLE text-H01.
  PARAMETERS: p_infile TYPE rlgrap-filename LOWER CASE OBLIGATORY.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK upload.
AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON VALUE-REQUEST FOR p_infile.
  PERFORM main1 CHANGING p_infile.
INITIALIZATION.
  PERFORM main2.
TOP-OF-PAGE.
  PERFORM main3.
...
```

`main1`, `main2`, and `main3` cannot to my knowledge pass any data to one another without global declaration. If the data is parsed from the uploaded file `p_infile` in `main1`, it cannot be accessed in `main2` or `main3`. Aside from omitting events all together, is there any way to abide by the warning but let data be passed over events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @vwegert so rightly said, it's almost impossible to write an ABAP program that doesn't have at least a few global variables (the selection screen and events enforce that, unfortunately).

One approach is to use a controller class, another is to have a main subroutine and have it call other subroutines as required, passing values as required. I tend to favour the latter approach in a lot of cases, if only because it's easier to split the subroutines into logical groupings in separate includes (doing so with classes can sometimes be a little ugly). It really is a matter of approach though, but the key thing is reducing global variables to a minimum - unfortunately too few ABAP developers that I've encountered care about such issues.

**Update**

@Christian has reminded me that as of ABAP AS 7.02, subroutines are [considered obsolete](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abenabap_subroutines.htm):

> Subroutines should no longer be created in new programs for the following reasons:
>
> - The parameter interface has clear weaknesses when compared with the parameter interface of methods, such as:
>
>   - positional parameters instead of keyword parameters
>   - no genuine input parameters in pass by reference
>   - typing is optional
>   - no optional parameters
> - Every subroutine implicitly belongs to the public interface of its program. Generally this is not desirable.
> - Calling subroutines externally is critical with regard to the assignment of the container program to a program group in the internal session. This assignment cannot generally be defined as static.

Those are all valid points and I think in light of that, using classes for modularisation is definitely the preferred approach (and from a purely aesthetic point of view, they also "fit" better with the syntax enhancements in 7.02 and later).

Comment: Thank you. You're certainly right about too few ABAPers caring - but someone must lead by example. I have a copy of _Introduction to ABAP Programming for SAP, Third Edition_ by Cengage Learning in front of me, and the example program `ZCHECK` on page 294 contains only global variables. Do you know of any good resources to helpful to an ABAPer trying to adhere to programming standards?

Comment: I think you're on the right track using the Extended Program Check (`SLIN`). If you're looking for something to read, [Official ABAP Programming Guidelines](https://www.sap-press.com/official-abap-programming-guidelines_2093/) is an excellent reference.

Comment: @mjturner I read in documentation that subroutines are obsolete.

Comment: @Christian Yes, you're right - I believe that as of 7.02 `FORM` is considered an obsolete modularisation technique. I'll update my answer to expand on that a little bit.

Answer (score 6):

There are a variety of techniques - I prefer to code almost everything except for the basic selection screen handling in a separate controller class. The report simply defers to that class and calls its methods. Other than that - it's just a warning that you can ignore if you know what you're doing. Writing a program without any global variable at all will certainly not be practical - however, you should think at least twice before using global variables or attributes in a place where a method parameter would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. Since this I've been using ABAP Objects wherever possible. Also, thanks for getting IS INSTANCE OF implemented in 7.50! :)